# How to read from file and dynamically allocate an array of int

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I need to read some files containing a lot of numbers (int). Lines of every file are different.

```
1
3
5
2
1
3
2
```

I have to read one of those files and create an array of int dynamically.
I'm going to read the file twice because I'm not able to know the length of the file.
Do you know another way ?
This is what I did:

```
int main()
{
    int *array;
    int tmp, count;

    ifstream fin("inputfile");

    while(fin >> tmp)
        count++;

    array = new int[count];

    fin.close();
    fin.open("inputfile");
    int i=0;
    while(fin >> tmp)
        array[i++]=tmp;

    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use `std::vector`, it would simpler then?

Comment: Any reason why not?  You are using c++.

Comment: My teacher still didn't explain them.

Comment: Luckily either upvoted answers below explains how to use them in this case perfectly.

Comment: @DeniseMendezGomez Then you can't use `new` or C style arrays either, because your teacher won't have explained them.  Of, if he explained them before `std::vector`, he's completely incompetent to teach C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there are same numbers of int in a line for all files, you can get the count of line of the file by calculating the size of it, and then the lines of this file is equal to size(file)/(n*sizeof(int)), n is the number of int for every line. I think you can try instead of read the file twice.

Comment: And how, pray tell, is he going to get the size of it?  (In practice, the only way to accurately measure the size is by reading the file, and counting how many bytes you read.)

Comment: Not to mention that the number of characters it takes to represent an `int` can vary.

Comment: it's easy to konw how many bytes of a file include, because you can read the struct member about attribute of the file throught API function. It is worth mentioning that this way works in the condition of same number int in every line, doesn't it? and also how many bytes of a int including is not a problem, because it don't have effect on the final result in one machine

Comment: The number of bytes the OS sees in a file is _not_ necessarily the same thing as the number of bytes you can read from the file.  And `sizeof(int)` is irrelevant for a text file.  For the data he shows, where all of the integers are a single digit, his file will contain 2 bytes per int on Unix, and 3 under Windows.  This only holds, however, as long as there are only single digit integers, and there is no additional white space.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `std::vector` rather that a raw array.

That way you can add to the vector as you read each item, rather than having to read the file once in order to work out how many items are in the file and then again to populate the array.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    int tmp;

    ifstream fin("inputfile");

    while(fin >> tmp)
    {
        data.push_back(tmp)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idiomatic way of reading numbers from a file into an `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream is("inputfile");
  std::istream_iterator<int> start(is), end;
  std::vector<int> numbers(start, end);
  std::cout << "Read " << numbers.size() << " numbers" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1: I was about to post exactly the same but you beat me to it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use std::vector, you can add a count for in the while loop, if it reaches the up limit of the array, realloc another buffer with size*2 and copy the data to it, then start read the file again.

vector use the same logic.

Comment: The multiplier may vary.  (For `std::vector`, I've seen both 2 and 1.5.)